# req.body with res.render getting incomplete Vaule

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing a strange issue - using `req.body` to send the form input to another page, data is getting rendered while using a single word in from input example: "FullName", however, with space example: "Full Name" getting an only first string (full)it ignoring the word after space.

how to fix this issue

```html
<form class="" action="/addname" method="POST">
<div class="input-field col s5">
<i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
<input id="Name" type="text" name = "Name">
<label for="icon_prefix">Name</label>
</div>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn default" type="submit" name="action" >Next <i class="material-icons prefix">navigate_next</i></button>
</form>
```

```js
app.js

server.post('/addname', (req, res) => {
        const Name: req.body.Name;
        res.render('Userinfo', {Name});
});
```

```html
ejs

<p> <%=Name%></p>
```

Comment: Please try: const {Name} = req.body;    res.render('Userinfo', {Name});  in addition please share the jade file

Comment: `const Name: req.body.Name;` is invalid JavaScript and will not run. It will throw a `SyntaxError: ` instead. Can you please show the code you're _actually_ using? (reduced where necessary, of course, as per the instructions on how to create a reasonable [mcve])

Comment: @OronBen-David - tried as suggested but getting error { Name: undefined }

server.post('/name', (req, res) => {
    const {Name} = req.body.Name;
    console.log({Name})
    res.render('userinfo.ejs',{Name});
});

EJS.file 
<p> <%=Name%></p>

Comment: @KiKu please write: const {Name} = req.body;

Comment: Smae Error 
server.post('/name', (req, res) => {

    const {Name} = req.body;

    console.log({Name})
    res.render('userinfo.ejs',{Name});

});

getting a proper response  with console.log(req.body)

Comment: console.log(Name) prints the correct value?

Comment: No- Result is undefined

Comment: What is the output of console.log(req.body)?

Comment: getting the proper output - Full Name

Comment: Please share the full output of console.log(req.body)

Comment: { Name: 'kiiii kik',
  action: '' }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200358/discussion-between-oron-ben-david-and-kiku).

Comment: Lets continue on chat

Comment: I got the result -

    const obj = req.body;
    const Fullname = obj.Name;
Hope i am doing corract ...?

Comment: @KiKu I've posted my answer after checking it locally.

Comment: Thanks @OronBen-David- It's working

Comment: @KiKu Please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your app.js with the following code:

```
server.post('/addname', (req, res) => {
  const {Name} = req.body
  res.render('Userinfo', {Name});
});
```